# Show dupehammer in close reasons on iOS app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, close-dialog, dupehammer

In the screenshot below, Shadow Wizard has the ultimate power of the mighty dupehammer, but the tag badge is not shown in the question closed dialogue.

[image]

This may cause confusion for some users since it is uncommon for a question to be closed by a single member that is not a moderator of the site. Moreover, if the website version has it, the iOS app should also include it.

Comment: Pretty sure it's not shown because the info [isn't returned by the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/closed-details)

Comment: Feature-request for android-app too

Comment: Should I open a new question for the android app

Comment: That's tricky, the API is the same for both apps, and after it would be added to the API it would be trivial to change the design of each app. So not sure about it. Maybe better tag this with both and hope for the best. :)

Comment: I believe there should be two separate feature requests as different people work on each app.  This feature could be added to one platform and not the other.

Comment: Did a little research and found other examples of having the same feature request but opened two questions for different mobile platforms