# Show dupehammer in close reasons on Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, close-dialog, dupehammer

The original iOS feature request is at [Show dupehammer in close reasons on iOS app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290989/275420). This is simply the feature request for the Android app, since the two apps are maintained by different people.

Dupehammer should be shown in the question closed dialogue. Currently it is not. This may cause confusion for some users since it is uncommon for a question to be closed by a single member that is not a moderator of the site. Moreover, if the website version has it, the Android app should also include it.