# Improve formatting of dupehammer indication in the iOS app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, revisions-list, dupehammer

Contrary to the [question closed popup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290989/295232), the revisions list *does* include information about somebody using a [dupehammer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230865/295232) to close a question. However, it's badly formatted; it looks as if the tag name is part of the username (even though it does link to the corresponding tag badge page):

[image]

When (if?) development on the apps ever resumes (whether in-house or open source), can this be changed so that it looks like a tag badge, as it does on the website?

Comment: What if someone has username discussion or heavy or constant?

Comment: Yeah, that would be really confusing :)